# Delete required on input before submitted in ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I tried to validate by submitting a form by using ajax on codeigniter, when I want to insert data but only a few input fields only and input field that I do not use I try to hide, but attr required still running on the input field that I have hidden, how to solve this. so delete the required input field when hidden.

Views

```
<form id="fr" method="post" class="form-horizontal form-label-left">    
    <div class="form-group">        
        <label for="fullname">Section * :</label>
        <select name="section" class="form-control" required="required">
            <option value="">Select section</option>
            <option value="manager">Manager</option>
            <option value="head manager">Head Manager</option>
        </select>
        <span class="help-block"></span>    
    </div>  
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="nama">Kitchen * :</label>
        <input type="text" name="name_kitchen"  class="form-control" required="required" />
        <span class="help-block"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="nama">Resto * :</label>
        <input type="text" name="name_resto"  class="form-control" required="required" />
        <span class="help-block"></span>
    </div>  

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="fullname">&nbsp;</label><br>
        <button type="button" id="submit"  class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Simpan</button>
    </div>  
</form> 

<script>
    $("[name='section']").change(function(){
        var value=$(this).val();
        if(value == "manager"){
            $("[name='name_kitchen']").hide();
            $("[name='name_resto']").show();
        }else{
            $("[name='name_kitchen']").show();
            $("[name='name_resto']").hide();        
        }   
    });

    $("#submit").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: base_url+"add",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: $('#fr').serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                if(data.status) { 
                    $(".add-from-staff").toggle("slow");    
                    $("#fr").load(location.href + " #fr");
                    $('form#fr input[type="text"],texatrea, select').val('');                   
                }else {
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.inputerror.length; i++) 
                    {
                        $('[name="'+data.inputerror[i]+'"]').parent().parent().addClass('has-error');
                        $('[name="'+data.inputerror[i]+'"]').next().text(data.error_string[i]); 
                    }
                }
            },
            error: function (request, jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                 alert('Error');
                console.log(request.responseText);
            }       
        });     
    });     
</script>
```

Controllers

```
public function add() {
    $this->_validate();
    $insert = $this->My_models->_add();
    echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));          
}   

function _validate() {
    $data = array();
    $data['error_string'] = array();
    $data['inputerror'] = array();
    $data['status'] = TRUE;

    if($this->input->post('name_kitchen') == '')
    {
        $data['inputerror'][] = 'name_kitchen';
        $data['error_string'][] = 'Kitchen is required';
        $data['status'] = FALSE;
    }


    if($this->input->post('name_resto') == '')
    {
        $data['inputerror'][] = 'name_resto';
        $data['error_string'][] = 'Resto is required';
        $data['status'] = FALSE;
    }

    if($data['status'] === FALSE)
    {
        echo json_encode($data);
        exit();
    }
}
```

so how when I choose one of the select options that hide disabled required?

Answer (score 0):

In this example I would not use the `required` attribute. It is causing more headaches than it is worth. Instead, rely on the server-side validation.

To determine which "section" is in use it seems to me that passing another piece of info to the controller would be the easiest way to solve the problem. This could be done many different ways. Adding another hidden field is one option.

Somewhere inside the `<form>` add

```
<input type="hidden" id="use-section" name="use_section" value="">
```

It is not clear that you have a "default" section shown when you first show the page. If there is one then use that for the "value" in the above field.

During the handler

```
 $("[name='section']").change(function(){ ...
```

set the value of the "use_section" field.

```
var value=$(this).val();
$("#use-section").val(value);
```

You can evaluate the "use_section" in your controller, or in your case, in the model which is where I assume you are capturing the data posted.

```
if($this->input->post('use_section') === "manager")
{
    //get the fields you want
} 
else
{
     //get the other fields
}
```

I have a suggestion regarding `_validate()`. Instead of calling `exit()` to short-circuit `add()` return a value - TRUE if it works, or `$data` if it doesn't. The last few lines of `_validate()` become

```
if($data['status'] === FALSE)
{
    return $data;
}

return TRUE;
```

Then use this `add()` method

```
public function add()
{
    if(TRUE === ($status = $this->_validate()))
    {
        $insert = $this->My_models->_add();
        $status = array("status" => TRUE);              
    } 
    echo json_encode($status);
}
```

Use of `exit` or `die` in CodeIgniter is, IMO, not appropriate because it short-circuits the framework's designed execution flow.

Answer (score 0):

when u are hiding any div u can get the element and remove its required attribute using jquery

```
$("[name='name_kitchen']").removeAttr('required');

e.g:
$("#elementID").removeAttr('required');
```